# Best iOS Framework for Advanced network usage?

Tags: objective-c, networking, ios5

I need a network framework that can post raw data such as 0x01. or any raw data i need posted to a server. Not just a HTTP request. I can't seem to find any network frameworks like this. Also, If there are none that currently exist. How would i go about writing the sockets? I can't seem to get that down. which is why i am looking for a existing framework. Thanks for any help. I have tried using sockets but, I was unable to convert the CFArrayRef. I tried many things, But, It crashed every time i tested. So, I am running out of options but to use a prebuilt framework.

Note, I do not want to do only a request like:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 4

0x01
```

No, I would like to send RAW data so, The following would be sent to the remote server through a socket.

```
0x01
```

This would not be visible raw text however, It would be converted to a data string then sent. I know how to convert most of the stuff i need to do, Its the sending and receiving the response I need the framework for or something that'd work. Any tutorials online or examples on how to do something similar that I can modify to fit to my needs would be greatly appreciated.

How do i send raw data to a socket? 
Where do i find a framework like this? 
Can you provide tutorials that I can modify to fit my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best framework for this is [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/). While it allows sending arbitrary data on the socket, it also provides very useful abstraction of much of the busywork of socket management. Look particularly a the GCD version that replaces the older RunLoop based code.

I've built several low-level protocols on this stack. I recommend it highly.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [raw sockets](https://discussions.apple.com/message/7815634?messageID=7815634) or the [CFStream API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html). I recommend the latter.

Comment: I'll take a look at both of those links, Give me a few minutes. thank you

Comment: @marcog I'm really not sure why you deleted that question. I could see future users asking the same question, and obviously my answer cleared it up for you.